# how to modify an existing java application to take advantage of nodejs features?

Tags: node.js, tomcat

Basically, I have an existing java application running on apache tomcat.

But I want to check if nodejs can help any how in scaling the existing java application(i.e. able to handle large no of requests due to event driven nature of node.js) so that i don't have to change the code of java application... So i came up with an **architecture** as follows:-

I want to take requests through node.js server(i.e. use the property of node.js to handle large no of requests as compared to apache tomcat) and pass it to apache tomcat through a message queue in between(it can be any. Mostly i m interested in using ActiveMQ as both tomcat and activemq are apache products).

I want to pass the response back to nodejs server from apache tomcat..(this seems little tricky, ie how to maintain which request the response should be served)

I want to confirm whether such an architecture is possible. If yes, then how..??? If no, then please suggest something else...

Comment: The Servlet 3.0 specification supports asynchronous request handling. It's not the same as Node's event loop, and unlike node.js modules most Java libraries are not written async from the ground up, but like arkoak suggested you might be able to migrate IO-bound parts of your app to an async model without completely rewriting all of it. Another, more drastic change might be to move to Undertow or Play Framework built with async in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is fast because it uses async IO. Meaning, when there is a file operation, it does not block the next operation and lets the server do other things on the same thread.

This changes how the programs on node.js work and event driven code has to be used.

The mechanism you are thinking about will only help in cases if you can breakdown a request into several tasks on the node.js server and call your apache server with appropriate parameters for each of the sub-task asynchronously, this will mean multiple tasks will be started on the same request by node.js and node.js will wait for the events for each task to finish.

This might be a lot of work and will be meaning that your migrate your controller logic to node.js and keep your views/html etc and data access layer in java.

Do note that if you cannot start tasks in parallel for a single request , due to the type of logic on the Apache side, you will end up re-developing the whole app before you get any considerable performance improvement.

A better approach can be to do the changes in steps targeting a much faster backend. Some of the steps are outlined below

1. Make slow parts of your application API based using json or xml on the server side and sending views using a single or multiple html static files not requiring processing. Adding a cache for static html can help too. Will need a lot of development on frontend.
2. Move heavy time-cost api calls to node.js server running on the same server, connecting to the same db/data sources.